# Datatables ajax authenticated data display username

Tags: ajax, datatables, basic-authentication

I'm building a datatable using ajax data which is provides customer data after authentication.  Is there a way to pickup the username during authentication and display it on the page to clearly indicate that the table contains the customer's personalised data?

Can I have the username stored in the ajax data file as the "dataSrc".

```
 {
   "username": [
  [
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3"
     ]
   ]
 }
```

Then it could be picked up as a variable and then displayed on the page.

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "data/customerdata.txt",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataSrc": function(...
    },
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I am sure there is. Exactly how depends on the type of authentication.

Comment: If you can get the username in the server-side script which populates your returned data then it's possible to add it to the returned data and then pick it up in your script

Comment: Where should the information be stored in the ajax data file? 
`      {
  "data": [
      [
        "item1",
        "item2",
        "item3"
      ], 
      [
        "item1",
        "item2",
        "item3"
      ] 
    ]
}`

Comment: @annoyingmouse I've updated my question to explain what I would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
"dataSrc": function (json){
    console.log(json.username); // Should output your array e.g. ["item1", "item2","item3"]
    $.each(json.username, function(k, v){
        console.log(k, v) // Should output each element of your array e.g 0 and item1 then 1 and item2 and then finally 2 and item3
        // You can display what you want on the page from this data.
    });
    return json.data; // returns the data to the table so it can be drawn.
}
```

Hope that that helps.

Comment: Should the json code should look like this?
`{
    "username": [  
        {
            "customer1": [
                [
                    "item1",
                    "item2",
                    "item3"
                ],
                [
                    "item1",
                    "item2",
                    "item3"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Then I would like to pickup "customer1" in as the table title or caption

Comment: @lbriquet the structure of your json is up to you really. It's possible to get the key from a json key value pair but it's much easier to get the value if you know the key. If you paste your json above into a service like http://jsonlint.com/ then it's perfectly valid but I'd suggest, if you're wanting to access "customer1" as a string for putting into the DOM, that you do something like this instead: `{"username": {"name": "customer1", "items": [["item1", "item2", "item3"],["item1", "item2", "item3"]]}}`. That way you can use `console.log(json.username.name)`. Hope that helps.